# Como agregar una fecha desde Java a un sql

Tags: java

Estoy generando un mantenimiento de una base de SQL, tengo el botón para agregar el cual lleva la siguiente configuración:

```
private void btModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (this.validarDatos()) {
            Paciente pac = new Paciente();
            pac.setnum_asegurado(Integer.parseInt(txtnum_asegurado.getText()));
            pac.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
            pac.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText());
            pac.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText()));
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");
                String fecha = formato.format(pac.getfecha_nacimiento());
               // pac.setfecha_nacimiento((Date) new SimpleDateFormat ("YYYY/MM/dd").parse(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()));

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            pac.sete_mail(txte_mail.getText());
            pac.setTelefono(Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText()));
            pac.setProfesion(txtProfesion.getText());
            int res = this.pacBo.modificar(pac);
            switch (res) {
                case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente Modificado Correctamente.");
                  break;
                case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo conectar a la BD.");
                  break;
                case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problemas Almancenando Datos.");
                  break;  
                case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Modificando Datos en la BD.");
                  break;  
            }
            llenarTabla();
            limpiar();
        }
```

Me envia este error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
>       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
>       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
>       at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
>       at ventanas.MantPaciente.btModificarActionPerformed(MantPaciente.java:395)
>       at ventanas.MantPaciente.access$200(MantPaciente.java:23)
>       at ventanas.MantPaciente$4.actionPerformed(MantPaciente.java:185)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.

Como puedo modificar esto para que me acepte el formato de la fecha! en la base sql me aparece (YYYY-MM-dd)

Comment: Hola Felix. Creo que es la segunda vez que noto que le pones la etiqueta `javascript` a tus preguntas. Javascript no es lo mismo que Java.

Comment: Sorry sigo aprendiendo!! gracias por el dato! y estoy como desenrredando un espaguetti!

Comment: Adelante amigo, no te rindas! :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que en la sentencia siguiente:

```
String fecha = formato.format(pac.getfecha_nacimiento());
```

... le estás pasando `null` al método `format`. O sea que `pac.getfecha_nacimiento()` devuelve `null`, lo que me parece normal, ya que acabas de crear una nueva instancia de `Paciente`.

Observando el resto del programa, parece que en vez de `pac.getfecha_nacimiento()`, deberías estar pasándole el valor de algún textbox, tal vez `txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()` que tienes en la porción de código comentada?

```
String fecha = formato.format(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText());
```

Comment: ?? Comentarios? eso donde lo localizo?

Comment: Justo debajo, donde @sstan marcó el problema, ahí está la sentencia comentada

Answer (score 0):

Pues de esta forma es que yo lo hago y me funciona de maravilla en mysql.

Obtengo la fecha del sistema y le doy formato, luego lo almaceno en una variable fecha de tipo String.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date =new Date();
String fechaHora = "";

fechaHora = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Te recomiendo o a cualquiera que presente un error parecido o de cualquier indole que agrege mensajes en consola con el dato para ver que esta obteniendo los datos.